# Обязятельно ли удалять массив с нулевым размером?

Tags: c++, указатели, память, утечка-памяти

Допустим, есть такой код:

```
cin >> size;
data = new color[size.x * size.y];
```

В случае, если размер не нулевой, data передаётся классу, который её удалит
Возникнет ли утечка памяти, если размер окажется нулевым?

Или всё же следует сделать проверку на размер до создания массива? (или удалять нулевой)

```
cin >> size;
data = size.x * size.y > 0 ? new color[size.x * size.y] : nullptr;
```

Comment: Конечно нужно удалять.

Comment: Я бы сказал, конечно следует проверять значение размера до создания массива.  С нулевым размером  логика всего кода, где используется этот массив, разрушится,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну, если я верно понимаю пункт 6.7.5.4.1 стандарта, то выделять нулевой размер вы можете, но использовать полученный указатель - нет

> The effect of indirecting through a pointer returned from a request for zero size is undefined

Но все, что выделено - должно быть освобождено. Вполне может быть так, что память выделяется - просто для того, чтобы обеспечить требование стандарта, что два выделения памяти должны давать разные указатели. Или как-то иначе изменяет структуры менеджера памяти. Так что освобождать такую память все равно надо.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*